# KO] PHP extension "intl" not found, please install it - required

Tags: php, linux, servidor, symfony, symfony5

H.
Estoy empezando a leer Symfony-la-via-rapida.
Uno de los primeros pasos es comprobar los requerimientos:
`symfony book:check-requirements`
Y me da los siguientes errores:

```
$ symfony book:check-requirements | grep KO
[KO] PHP extension "pdo_pgsql" not found, please install it - required
[KO] PHP extension "amqp" not found, optional - needed only for chapter 32
[KO] PHP extension "intl" not found, please install it - required
[KO] PHP extension "redis" not found, optional - needed only for chapter 31
[KO] Cannot find the Yarn package manager, please install it https://yarnpkg.com/
```

Primero me he centrado en solucionar el intl (por que es el primero que me salia).
Probé primero a instalar la que creia que era,... y luego me volví loco instalando ...

```
sudo apt-get install php8-intl
sudo apt-get install php8.0-intl
sudo apt-get install php8.1.2-intl
sudo apt-get install php8.1.1-intl
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
sudo apt-get install php8.1.3-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

Ejecute el `service apache2 restart` de vez en cuanto, pero nada, los KO persisten.

Estoy usando:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.3
Release:    20.3
Codename:   una
```

Acabo de ejecutar php-v y me da lo siguiente:

```
e-rick@erick-H61M-D2-B3:~$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/intl (/usr/lib/php/20210902/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/intl.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.1.3 (cli) (built: Feb 21 2022 14:48:42) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: debes instalar `php8-pgsql`, ¿no?

Comment: Estaba intentando solucionar primero en del intl. 
Luego ya iria con los otros 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al tratar de instalar librerías para otras versiones de PHP se crearon carpetas que no necesitas. Mi recomendación es desinstalar todas esas versiones de PHP y volver a instalar solo la que realmente vas a usar.

Primero deshabilita desde la terminal los módulos de apache que tengas habilitados, por ejemplo:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.1
```

**PRECAUCIÓN:** No ejecutes estos comandos hasta estar seguro de que la lista de paquetes a eliminar no va a afectar el funcionamiento del sistema y, de preferencia, crea un punto de restauración con Timeshift, para poder volver al estado actual en caso de que algo salga mal.

**IMPORTANTE:** El parámetro `purge` es similar a `remove`, excepto que aparte de desinstalar, también tratará de eliminar archivos de configuración y directorios.

Para desinstalar, tomé el siguiente comando de [esta respuesta](https://askubuntu.com/a/187278) (en inglés). Copia y pega en la terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

O, si no quieres tomar riesgos de que se vaya a desinstalar algo que no debas, como `phpmyadmin` o `kdevelop-php`, primero genera la lista de paquetes que coinciden:

```
dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "
```

Esto te va a generar una lista como la siguiente, ten en cuenta que yo tengo instalado PHP 7.4 (separo en líneas para ver mejor):

```
kdevelop-php libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.4
php php-bcmath php-bz2 php-common php-curl php-gd
php-google-recaptcha php-json php-mbstring php-mysql
php-phpmyadmin-motranslator php-phpmyadmin-shapefile
php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser php-phpseclib php-psr-cache
php-psr-container php-psr-log php-symfony-cache
php-symfony-cache-contracts php-symfony-expression-language
php-symfony-service-contracts php-symfony-var-exporter
php-tcpdf php-twig php-twig-extensions php-xdebug php-xml
php-zip php7.4 php7.4-bcmath php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli php7.4-common
php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-mysql
php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline php7.4-xml php7.4-zip phpmyadmin
```

Puedes copiar esa lista y comenzar a desinstalar por partes, omitiendo los nombres que desconozcas, por ejemplo, de las dos primeras líneas se quita `kdevelop-php`:

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.4 php php-bcmath php-bz2 php-common php-curl php-gd
```

### Instalar nuevamente PHP

Sigue la guía que usaste la primera vez que, en resumen, son los siguientes pasos:

1. Asegurarte de que el sistema está actualizado, ya sea desde la terminal o el gestor de actualizaciones
2. Instalar dependencias, creo que solo `software-properties-common` y, si ya lo hiciste, omite este paso
3. Agregar repositorio `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` o el que sugieran en esa guía
4. Instalar PHP, con librería de apache y extensiones deseadas
5. Editar `php.ini` para configurar de acuerdo a tus necesidades, habilitando extensiones
6. Habilitar módulo de PHP, por ejemplo: `sudo a2enmod php8.1`
7. Reiniciar apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

**Recuerda:** Si algo falló, puedes usar Timeshift para volver al punto de restauración que creaste y volver a intentar.

Si todo va como se esperaba, crea otro punto de restauración antes de seguir modificando.

### Más extensiones

Ejecuta los comandos de la guía que seguiste para instalar PHP 8 para agregar librerías, sería algo como `sudo apt install php8.1-intl`

Después de instalar las extensiones, desde la terminal edita `php.ini` para habilitarlas; recuerda poner en la ruta la versión de PHP que estás usando, por ejemplo:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Para habilitar la extensión, seguramente ya existe la línea y debes descomentarla, quitando el `;` del inicio. Para buscar desde nano, usa <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

```
;extension=intl
```

Si no existe la línea, entonces agrégala, en cualquier caso, debe quedar así:

```
extension=intl
```

Guarda los cambios con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> y sal del editor con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, después reinicia Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comprueba nuevamente los requerimientos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, No me ha solucionado el problema pero asi voy abanzando.
No se si me puedes decir, ¿como se que version de php se esta usando en cada momento?¿Es normal que tenga 8 versiones de php en la carpeta php?

Comment: @E.rick, edité la respuesta para agregar comandos de desinstalación. No olvides crear primero un punto de restauración.

Comment: Para saber la versión de PHP que ejecuta apache, crea un archivo `info.php` en la raíz (suele ser `/var/www/html`) con `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` y abre en el navegador `http://localhost/info.php`, en el encabezado verás la versión.